# How to diable IME in javafx password field

Tags: javafx, passwords, ime

In a web page, a password filed can be set to disable microsoft IME for preventing users input other language characters. for example chinese or japnese characters can't be input in that filed.

but in javafx UI, it is easy for me to put a chinese character into a password filed. who knows how to disable the microsoft IME when I input characters in a password filed? I just want to input only number, signs, and english characters in password field.

Comment: the use of passwords including non-Latin characters increases security.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to limit the range of characters that can be used for a password, you can test this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\+]*");

PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
passwordField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
    if(pattern.matcher(change.getText()).matches()) {
        return change;
    }

    return null;
}));
```

Comment: it's not a perfect solution. in web page, if you change input method to chinese , when you press the key, the password will be also inputted. it looks like you didn't change input method to chinese. but if you use this code as a filter, you can't input anything when your input method is chinese.

Comment: This requires a separate KeyEvents capture buffer. In theory, it looks simple, but actually there are a lot of underwater stones - the state of Caps Lock, the position of the cursor ...